# Can't compile a scheme function

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme

New to scheme here. I'm trying to compile a scheme function, `range`. It's very simple - it takes a `start`, `step` and `stop` list `L` and makes a new list where every element = stepAmt + curStep.

For  example: (range '(0 2 7)) => (0 2 4 6), (range '(2 2 0)) => ()

When I try to compile

```
(define (helper2(start stepAmt stop curStep newList)
(if (> start stop)
    '()
    (if (> (+ stepAmt curStep) stop)
        newList
        (helper2 (start stepAmt stop (+ stepAmt curStep) (concat newList (+stepAmt curStep))))))))
```

I get the error

> Ill-formed special form: (define helper2 (start stepamt stop curstep newlist) (if ... ... ...))

I'm not sure what it means. I've double checked my logic and parentheses and can't figure it out.

This is the function that will call that function:

```
(define (example L)
(let (
    (start (car L))
    (curStep (car (cdr L)))
    (step (car (cdr L)))
    (stop (car (cdr (cdr L))))
    )
    (helper2 (start step stop curStep '()))
)
```

)

Any pointers would be great. I'm not sure if it's a typo or a logical error. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @iaacp. Use (helper2 start step stop curStep '() in your example function and fix the similar problem in helper2. In Scheme it is not allowed to insert extra parentheses. The parenthesis in (start step ...) means: Call the function given by start with arguments step, ... . Note that the solution Rajesh gives has no such parentheses.

Comment: If you have a second question, please post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not

```
(define helper2 (some arguments go here)
   definition goes here)
```

but

```
(define (helper2 some arguments go here)
  definition goes here)
```

The way to remember this is that what goes after `define` looks just like a call to the function you're defining. "Here's how to deal with a call like `(helper2 some arguments go here)`: ..."

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed the errors and now it compiles, but doesn't run quite correctly :)

Comment: You now have a kinda-similar mistake in the body of `helper2`, where you say `(helper2 (start stepAmt ...))`. I think your brain hasn't yet fully come to terms with where parentheses go in Scheme! You just want `(helper2 start stepAmt ...)`. There's a similar problem (which may actually be the one that's failing) in your definition of `example`.

Comment: You're right. I keep making stupid mistakes like that. Luckily, I've got it to a point now where I can properly debug it - as I think all parentheses problems are gone. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Look carefully at where you've put the parentheses:

```
(define helper2(start stepAmt stop curStep newList) ...
```

versus

```
(define (example L) ...
```

Comment: Agh! Thanks for that. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same compile error. Do you see anything else?

Comment: You're getting *exactly* the same error? The one that says "Ill-formed special form: (define helper2 (start stepamt stop curstep newlist) (if ... ... ...))"? Did you remember to save your source code after changing it?

Comment: Oh I see, you changed the code but it's still not correct. You now have too many parentheses.

Comment: Yeah, I updated it now. Now it compiles, but when I run it as (example '(0 2 7)), I get the error `The object 0 is not applicable.` I'm guessing it's a logical error now.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using DrRacket?
This works:

```
#lang racket

(define (helper2 start stepAmt stop curStep newList)
(if (> start stop)
    '()
    (if (> (+ stepAmt curStep) stop)
        newList
        (helper2 start stepAmt stop (+ stepAmt curStep) (concat newList (+ stepAmt curStep))))))

(define (concat l elm)
  (append l (list elm)))

(define (example L)
(let (
    (start (car L))
    (curStep (car (cdr L)))
    (step (car (cdr L)))
    (stop (car (cdr (cdr L))))
    )
    (helper2 start step stop curStep '())
))
```